# Do I need multiple accounts in Facebook for each of my product site?

Tags: facebook

I've a dozen sites which include for-profit ones as well as for charity. For each site I've created a Facebook company/charity account. After creating those accounts it dawned on me that I could as well have created a new page for each of my site from my personal account only even if a site has multiple product pages.

What'll be the right strategy? Also as per Facebook terms we can have only single personal account. I do have single personal account only but for each site I've created only company pages. I hope I'm not violating the facebook terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Facebook your meant to set up the company / organizations account so that its managed by a personal account, you can also add more admin / users to the company account once its set up

To do this log in to your personal account and from there set up a bussiness / organization account.

Next time you log in to your personal account you'll get a section in the left hand side called "pages and ads" where you can manage multiple companys accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple Facebook fan pages from one single account in Facebook, you don’t need unique Facebook accounts to manage them.

If you've created multiple accounts, you can also combine them.